# How do I change a Perl Readonly scalar in a module for a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, readonly, readonly-variable

The only help I've found on the internet so far is [this blog](https://blog.plenz.com/2013-01/modify-a-readonly-scalar-in-perl-for-testing-purposes.html). Which I thought was going to get me there, but I don't think it's actually changing the values in my module. I made a sample to show what I mean.

```
package Module;

use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Readonly   qw( );

use parent     qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
   &GetReadonly
);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
   all => [ @EXPORT_OK ] );

Readonly::Scalar my $HOST => 'host.web.server.com';

sub GetReadonly
{
   return $HOST;
}

1;
```

And the test code:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More 'no_plan';
use Module qw/ :all /;

is($Module::HOST, 'host.web.server.com');     # HOST == undef

my $fake_host = 'fakemail.web.server.com';

{
   no warnings 'redefine';
   local *Readonly::Scalar::STORE = sub { ${$_[0]} = $_[1]; };
   $Module::HOST = $fake_host;
}

is(GetReadonly(), $fake_host);      # Returns host.web.server.com
```

If I use the `Module::HOST` from the blog, I get a bareword compile error.

Is there some better way to mock a Readonly for a unit test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog was probably written in the old days when [Readonly](http://p3rl.org/Readonly) was implemented in pure Perl using [tie](http://p3rl.org/tie). Nowadays, Readonly is implemented using XS. To make a variable not readonly anymore, you can call

```
Internals::SvREADONLY( $Module::HOST, 0 );
```

To be able to access the variable from outside of the module, it must be declared [our](http://p3rl.org/our), not [my](http://p3rl.org/my) (as the blog correctly shows).

But the main question is: why do you need to test a different value in the variable, if the variable isn't supposed to be writable?

Comment: I am unit testing, so I want access to private things. In this case, I want to change the mail server and validate an error condition. We don't normally want this information public, so I'd rather not make it an our variable if I don't have to.

Comment: In case you're wondering, if I change the variable to our, your solution works great. If there's anyway to keep it a scoped within the module, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @EricFossum What's the difference between exposing the variable directly via `our`, or exposing it via the exported function `GetReadOnly()`?

Comment: That function was just for testing if I set it. Nothing returns that value in my prod. code.

Comment: What error condition do you try to validate? Wouldn't it be better to mock a connection/request?

Comment: I think I could mock the `Net::SMTP->new` call, just trying to use as much of the real function as possible. The bad host request is coming back pretty much instantly, so I wasn't too worried about timeouts.

Comment: If your production code uses the `GetReadonly` function to access the value, you can overwrite that in your test.